# Qt C++ How to preform copy of an Hash to a Map

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying some things in Qt and trying to understand containers but I hit a brick wall.

```
QHash<int, QString> mHash;

    mHash.insert(3, "Nocas");
    mHash.insert(1, "Andre");
    mHash.insert(2, "Diana"); //overrides
    mHash.insertMulti(5, "Batatas"); //overides all keys '5'

    qDebug() << "\nHash.keys()\n";

    foreach(int i, mHash.keys())
    {
        qDebug() << i << " -> " << mHash[i];
    }

    qDebug() << "\nHash Values\n";

    foreach(QString value, mHash)
    {
        qDebug() << "Value: " << value;
    }

     qDebug() << "\nPre Copy\n";

    QHashIterator<int, QString> Hit(mHash);

    while (Hit.hasNext())
    {
        Hit.next();
        qDebug() << Hit.key() << " = " << Hit.value();

    }

    QMap<int, QString> HMap;

    QMutableMapIterator<int, QString> it2h(HMap);

    //Copy Hash to Map

    while (Hit.hasNext())
    {
        Hit.next();
        HMap.insert(Hit.key(), Hit.value());
    }

    qDebug() << "Print map: \n";

    while (it2h.hasNext())
    {
        it2h.next();
        qDebug() << it2h.key() << " = " << it2h.value();
    }
```

I don't understand why this:

```
   while (Hit.hasNext())
    {
        Hit.next();
        HMap.insert(Hit.key(), Hit.value());
    }
```

doesn't work.

I saw the literature but I don't really understand it.
I tried changing iterators.

```
QMap<int, int>::const_iterator i;
```

using foreach, for...still nothing never outputs.

### Output is:

```
Hash.keys()

5  ->  "Batatas"
1  ->  "Andre"
3  ->  "Nocas"
2  ->  "Diana"

Hash Values

Value:  "Batatas"
Value:  "Andre"
Value:  "Nocas"
Value:  "Diana"

Pre Copy

5  =  "Batatas"
1  =  "Andre"
3  =  "Nocas"
2  =  "Diana"

Print map:
```

---

As you can see after "Print map:" I was expecting the values.

Comment: What does **"doesn't work"** mean? What is the ouput from you code? How is it different from what you expected?

Comment: Sorry, I added the output that I get from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QHashIterator<int, QString> Hit(mHash);

while (Hit.hasNext())
{
    Hit.next();
    qDebug() << Hit.key() << " = " << Hit.value();

}
```

This codes creates a iterator to the hash map and iterates through it such that the `hasNext` function is `false`. This works correctly as evidenced by the output.

```
QMap<int, QString> HMap;

QMutableMapIterator<int, QString> it2h(HMap);

//Copy Hash to Map

while (Hit.hasNext())
{
    Hit.next();
    HMap.insert(Hit.key(), Hit.value());
}
```

Next, the code tries to iterate through `Hit` again **but it's already at the end** and doesn't execute any loops. This should be verifiable by stepping through with a debugger or adding print statements to the for loop.

Since the above loop doesn't execute nothing is copied and therefore the `QMap` doesn't have any values. The `Hit` iterator needs to be reset, or a new one created, so that it's pointing to the start of the hash map before trying to iterate to do the copying.

---

It looks like there is a `toFront` API to reset the iterator back to the front so that iteration can begin again, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhashiterator.html#toFront. I don't have access to QT to test and verify this behaves as I anticpate.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it thanks to **James Adkison** answer by using **hasPrevious()** since he said the pointer would be pointing at the end.

```
QMap<int, QString> HMap; //I created the map

while (Hit.hasPrevious()) //used hasPrevious() to work my way back to the start
{
    Hit.previous(); //pointed to previous on every loop
    HMap.insert(Hit.key(), Hit.value()); //inserted on map

}

QMutableMapIterator<int, QString> itM(HMap);

qDebug() << "\nPost Copy\n";

while (itM.hasNext())
{
    itM.next();
    qDebug() << itM.key() << " = " << itM.value();
}
```

and since my objective was to use map to organize the keys it worked like a charm.

This is the final solution I used:

```
Hit.toFront();
while (Hit.hasNext())
{
    Hit.next();
    HMap.insert(Hit.key(), Hit.value());

}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the problematic code isn't really the code you're using **because inside the for loop** it is calling `Hit.hasNext();` instead of `Hit.next();`.

Comment: Yes ofc, sorry, i didn't notice that.I corrected and works very well. Thank you very much. You where a huge help. Good year to you sir. I wish you the best of luck.